# How to create code to continue count timer on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Somebody please help, i want to create app with vb.net, but the problem is how to create code on vb.net to continue the timer billing count, when the computer goes down it's cause the electric down and then i turn on back of computer and the timer of billing app is continue again. thank you all for the answer. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Post the relevant code of your app

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you don't need a timer at all. Just save the start time to database or to text file on your computer. Then you can always find the timer value no matter if your computer was down (current time minus start time).

Comment: Ok thank you i'll try your answ, can you give me the web tuts or link about my question.